# Unable to retain shell size in SWT

Tags: java, swt

I have an SWT application where I have a logger window displayed to the user. This window has a table in it and is divided into few columns. My requirement is that if a user changes the column size or the shell (window size) and then closes the window, the sizes of window and columns should be retained the next time he opens the same window so that his preference of size if retained. I am able to achieve this for the columns of the table by using

```java
TableColumn[] columns = viewer.getTable().getColumns();
LogViewerColumnSize.INSTANCE.setColumnProperties(columns);
```

And when I open the shell again I am setting the size of each column from the data. 
However the same I am not able to get for the shell. 
I have tried the following way -

```java
LogViewerColumnSize.INSTANCE.setLoggerSize(shell.getSize());
```

And when I open the shell again -

```java
Point shellSize = LogViewerColumnSize.INSTANCE.getLoggerSize(); 
if(shellSize != null) 
    shell.setSize(shellSize);
```

It is setting to the default value of the shell size again.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling `Shell.pack()` after this `setSize` call the `pack` call will override the size as it calls `setSize` using the computed default size.

So don't call `pack` if you have set the size.

Comment: Thanks greg!! Works fine now!